# Connection doesn't established when connect to sql server via php

Tags: php, driver, sqlsrv

I have already Docker and SqlServer which is works normally. Now i want to connect to sql server with php. it gives me `could not find driver` error. I use php 8 on centos 7. How can i fix it?

Comment: [This page from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac) will give you all the info needed to install and/or configure the driver for PHP 8.0

Comment: Are you using wamp or something else ?

Comment: Thanks for all. I fixed it from links (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15)